# stop div moving outside grid when merging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i've implemented a jquery drag and drop with selection capabilities and created a grid-esque interface. I've now added a merge function for the div's but the problem is when i merge B & F in my current code

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fAu6p/1/)**

the last div "jumps" out of my grid and i'm left with a white space.

This is how i'm merging the divs based on the index position of whats on my grid

```
cells[0].append(cells[1].html());
        cells[1].remove();
```

Can someone help me out with this one as its driving me crazy :( i'm so close to finishing this off but without the merge working properly i'm at a loss

thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It doesn't jump out of your grid, you're rearranging the grid.

Comment: you might need something like this: http://masonry.desandro.com/ to arrange the boxes after the merge

Comment: great call on masonry-its something that i'd actually looked at during my initial research and completely forgot about, i now have this completely working the way i'd like  - :)

Comment: Ok almost there, merge now works perfectly and cells are staying where they should after implementing Masonry but is there a way to constrain masonry to a fixed area?? when dragging divs masonry will resize the parent div and alter the grid shape :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is how floating works. As `B+F` take up more height than one row it shifts all following elements to the right to preserve the order. There's no worakround except using another kind of grid with absolute positioning or fixed droppables for example.